# Django over Werkzeug for debugging/deploying?

Tags: django, wsgi, werkzeug

i've just tried the "django_extensions", and it seems it has good stuff, but there are two questions about that:
1 - when using runserver_plus it seems that the webpage dont update when i update the code (and save it) and to take changes effects, i must break the process and reload the server again! on runserver that chips with django, every change i made on any file will take effect after refrshing the webpage, i've checked both runserver.py and runserver_plus.py and they've both the option of reloading ON, so where is the problem?
2 - is Werkzeug here only for debugging purpose, mean; can't use it for deploying without using Apache or Nginx or Lighty, because am on Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

As for the first question:
There was a regression in the recent versions of werkzeug, which was fixed with this commit:
https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/commit/3803c38a87d9770c6e1c8194763d80d7222706b8
For now you can use older werkzeug version (0.5.x should be ok) or the version from git, wich includes this fix.

Second question i can't understand.